# Error when installing R with Homebrew

Tags: r, homebrew

I'm trying to install r with homebrew using Mountain Lion. On my first try the install failed because I didn't have XQuartz installed. Tried installing again with brew install r and received this error. I also tried brew install r --env=std with the same results. Thanks!

```
○ → brew install r --env=std
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.0.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/r-3.0.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.0.2 --with-aqua --enable-R-framework --with-lapack
==> make
     54634 Trace/BPT trap: 5       | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL ../../../bin/R --vanilla --slave > /dev/null
make[3]: *** [all] Error 133
make[2]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make: *** [R] Error 1
```